# Omit made up columns from results

Tags: mysql

So I have a complicated `INSERT` query which puts information into a relational table based on information pulled from another table and with given variables.

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO relational (class_id, teacher_id, student_id)
VALUES (
    (SELECT `id`,
        (`name` = "John Smith") as exact_score,
        (`name` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]") as reg_score,
        (MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ("John Smith")) as match_score
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE (`title` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]" || MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("John Smith"))
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN exact_score = 1 THEN exact_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score > 1 THEN reg_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score = 0 AND exact_score = 0 THEN match_score END DESC),
1, 1);
```

The regex is required because the name might be `Mr. John Smith` or `John Smith PH.d`, and the match is required because the name might be `jon smith` When the stored name is actually just `John Smith`.

The select query yields the results I am looking for 90% of the time, but the only real *column* that I need from it is `id`. The problem I'm running into is with the INSERT's expected column count vs. the column count that is returned by the query.

Right now the INSERT basically looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO relational (class_id, teacher_id, student_id) VALUES ({{returned id (desired)}}, {{exact score (undesired)}}, {{reg score (undesired)}}, {{match score (undesired)}}, 1, 1);
```

The last `1, 1` is provided by variables.

My question is, is there a way to select columns for the sake of ORDER BY, but then to omit them from the results?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `VALUES`; simplify the insert to

```
INSERT INTO t (class_id, teacher_id, student_id)
    SELECT id, 1, 1 FROM ...
```

To get rid of extra columns, make an extra level of SELECT:

```
SELECT a, b
    FROM (
        SELECT a, extra, b FROM ...
         ) AS x
```

But, you probably won't have any extra columns if you do

```
ORDER BY
    IF (`name` = "John Smith", 2, 
        IF (`name` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]", 1,
            MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ("John Smith")
       )   )
```